# Looping through worksheets and sorting data accordingly

Tags: vba, excel

Why does this code fail? I want it to loop through all the worksheets and sort the specified ranges.

The code works when I use

```
For ws each activeworkbook.worksheets
ws.activate
```

But does not work when I use the code below.

Can someone help me out and explain why VBA comes up with a runtime error 1004

I would also prefer to use a `For j = 2 to thisworkbook.worksheets.count`
but that does not work neither

```
Sub beautsort()

Dim LR As Long, LC As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'Starting fromt the last occupied cells and going upwards
    Lastrow = ws.Range("B30000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = Lastrow To 3 Step -1
        bLR = ws.Range("A" & i).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        LC = ws.Range("B" & i).End(xlToRight).Column

                    If ws.Range("B" & i).Value = "All Grps" Then
                        ws.Range(Range("B" & i).Offset(-1, -1), ws.Cells(bLR, LC)).Sort _
                                    key1:=ws.Range("B3"), Order1:=xlDescending
                    End If

    Next i

Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Qualify the range with the sheet reference like this: ws.Range(ws.Range("B" & i).Offset(-1, -1), ws.Cells(bLR, LC)).Sort _
                                    key1:=ws.Range("B3"), Order1:=xlDescending

Comment: Thank you very much sktneer ;)

Comment: You're welcome Koko! :)

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
ws.Range(Range("B" & i).Offset(-1, -1), ws.Cells(bLR, LC))
```

The unqualified reference `Range("B" & i).Offset(-1, -1)` will still refer to the current worksheet, meaning the overall range is between the current worksheet and the ws worksheet, which isn't possible and throws the error.

Qualifying the reference to be `ws.Range("B" & i).Offset(-1, -1)` will solve the issue.

Note that when using Range in the format Range(Range,Range), it's actually not necessary (and sometimes far clearer/simpler) to not qualify the outer range.

Try stepping through this:

```
Sub Referencing()

    With Range("B2:D4")

        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Select
        .Select
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Range("A1").Select
        .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Select
        Range("A1").Select
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Select
        .Range("A1").Select

    End With

End Sub
```

At the point of qualifying both the inner and outer ranges, the result may not be what's expected. The .range and .cell properties actually behave like offset properties. Qualifying the outer range sets the reference range to B2:D4, where B2 is the first row and first column. Qualifying the inner range then applies the same offset again.